# How to combine BooleanQuery and Filter for Lucene?

Tags: filter, lucene, categories

I'm wondering if there's a way to perform a filtered search in Lucene index with a combination of Filter and Query instead of a BooleanQuery?

Since performing a query causes calculation of relevance rating, we don't really need this when filtering documents by category or location.

For example: we have a query "happy new year" which should be performed within "Greeting Cards / XMas" category. So what we really need is to do a search within the category and then order the results by a relevance rating, based on a query text.

If we try to do it with a BooleanQuery, relevance rating calculation considers every term in a query (if I understand the mechanics correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [api](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html) - note how you can pass in both a filter and a query.